# How to set the language of Android Auto voice recognition during navigation?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-auto, google-assistant, waze

When I use voice recognition on my Android phone in apps Google Maps or Waze, it understands Hungarian language.
However when I plug the same phone to my car and trying to do the same thing via Android Auto, it will listen to me only in English.
I can speak English but the problem is that I want the apps to understand Hungarian street and city names which is practically impossible.

According to my understanding (correct me if I'm wrong), for some reason, apps used through Android Auto are getting voice recognition output from Google Assistant. And it seems that Google Assistant knows only a few languages, Hungarian is not included. However when using the phone on its own outside the car, apps don't use Google Assistant but something else (another Google voice recognition product, unsure about its name) which knows Hungarian.

Do you know any workaround for this?

My phone is a Samsung A51 running Android 11.
Version of my Android Auto installation is 7.3.620524-release.

Thanks!

**Update**: I deleted cache and data of Android app named Google, so Assistant got switched off. This leads to a partial solution because now Google Maps understands Hungarian speech but Waze still doesn't.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have source codes as I am just an end user in this scenario, not a developer.